# Insert into an access table from SQL using recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the following code to insert data in an access table from SQL using a recordset. This table is further used for other operations. While this is inserting the data into the table perfectly, the time taken by this huge. Should I use any other method to insert data into the table to reduce the time taken?

```
Do Until rs.EOF
          DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table (Alpha,Beta,Gamma) VALUES(" & _
          rs.Fields(0).Value & ",'" & rs.Fields(1).Value & "'," & rs.Fields(2).Value _
          & " );"
        rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your code

Comment: Are you inserting identical data into every row? Why do you keep doing it in a loop? Just run the sql once, you are running the same sql for every row in a table.

Comment: yes I am doing it in a loop. But what would be the best way so that I can insert the data in a single shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a linked table to the SQL table, say it's called `MyLinkedTable`
2. Create an Append query to append to your local Access table from your linked table. It will look something like this: `INSERT INTO MyAccessTable (Field1,Field2...) SELECT Field1,Field2... FROM MyLinkedTable;`

Answer (score 0):

If you could select the data in the SQL `UPDATE` statement instead looping in `VBA` it would take a fraction of the time as all the work would be done by the server side.

Comment: is it possible to do that is vba. My table is in access. This table is used for other operations.

Comment: The whole idea is that don't want to do this in VBA because it takes too long. You want do it all in SQL. Tell me, is the source table in the same database as the destination table?

Comment: Source database is in SQL but destination table is in access.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server? How do you connect to the source table?

Comment: Yes SQL Server. Apologies for confusion. I am connecting to SQL Server using ADODB.

Comment: If @ElectricLlama's answer works then that's the way to go. Otherwise you could try using a `Command` object for the insert, but I am not that would necessarily be quicker.

Comment: I assume that's the way to go because current method is time taking. Anyways thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do an INSERT INTO SELECT. We need more information on your RecordSet but you probably do not need it.

`'Here we go, with just one line! 
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table (Alpha,Beta,Gamma) SELECT column1, column2, column2 FROM YourTable"`

The SELECT statement is probably the same as the one you used for opening your Recordset. 
Good luck!

Comment: This will only work if "YourTable" is a linked table to the SQL Server.